# Characterizations of cycloid

Tags: curves

There are several constructions of a cycloid. I have some examples below. Are there any others?

1. Trace of a fixed point on a rolling circle
2. Evolute of another cycloid (the locus of all its centers of curvature)
3. Involute of another cycloid (trace of a pendulum constrained to another cycloid)
4. Envelope of a family of lines with uniformly varying angle and intercept

Comment: Have you tried http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/cycloid/cycloid.shtml? It's in French, but the website is full of relationships between curves, maybe you'll find «new» characterizations.

Comment: There are various characterisations of the cycloid in terms of mechanical properites if curvies.  For example, it is both a brachistochrone and a tautochrone for a constant force law parallel to the $y$-axis and a trajectory for such a force law, with force proportional to $\frac 1 {y^2}$.